# parent child relationship between panels using java swings

Tags: java, swing

I need to build a desktop application for client using Java Swing and `jdk 1.6`.
The requirement is to display a chain of elements (each element contains textfield, buttons, labels) in parent-child format, like this:

```
Parent1
    Child1  
    Child2  
    Child3  
        child3.1  
        child3.2  
// indentation will be used to display parent child relationship
```

It's similar to how a `JTree` looks, where each node contains buttons, labels etc.
Any help as how this can be implemented using swing components?

Comment: Try `Outline`, cited [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692); note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple vertical `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout` (1 column many rows) just add to each your element an `EmptyBorder` with left offset where left offset is calculated from element level (0 for root +10 for each level down).

Answer (score 1):

To keep all JTree functionalities, you can also use a custom cell renderer on the JTree.

```
JTree tree = new JTree(rootVector);
TreeCellRenderer renderer = new YourCellRenderer();
tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

And then define your own renderer:

```
class YourCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
  DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

  public YourCellRenderer() {
  }

  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
      boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
      boolean hasFocus) {
      //return the button, label or JPanel you need to render this node.
  }
}
```

Full example available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TreeCellRenderer.htm)